# HTML form that submits to a Perl script

Tags: html, forms, perl, validation

Ok, so if anyone out there can help me with this, I would be forever grateful. The form I have is for a conference so what the user has to do is select 3 morning classes and 3 afternoon classes. These are all checkboxes and an example of the code is as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ece_classes" value="name 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="ece_classes" value="name 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="ece_classes" value="name 3">
```

Now these are all in 1 table column while in another column next to these is a Priority list:

```
<select name="Priority">
  <option value="">
    --Select--
  </option>
  <option value="1">
    1
  </option>
  <option value="2">
    2
  </option>
  <option value="3">
    3
  </option>
</select>
```

My Perl script has the following pertaining to the checkboxes:

```
$finalmailbody .= "Morning Presenters: $testhash{ece_classes},\n\n";
```

Now, when the email is sent with all the info, instead of listing all 3 classes that were selected, it only lists the last one selected.

The perl scrip works for sending out all the users personal info and payment process' and what not but this is the only part of the script that I have no idea how to handle.

***Pretty much to sum up exactly what I'm looking for (since the above is probably very confusing) is the following:***

I have a form with a list of 15 morning classes and 15 afternoon classes followed by their personal information that is needed. The user must select 3 morning and 3 afternoon classes while also selecting the priority (1-3) of the classes. Once the form is submitted, it goes to /cgi-bin/forms/eceform.pl. In this perl script (which I did not create, I only know how to manipulate it for single string data), it fetches all this data and then emails it to a specified email address. I need to know how to print out the classes selected in the email since all the morning classes use the same name (ece_classes) and all the afternoon classes use the same name (ece_classes_a). I have never used perl before this and I'm finding this portion of this very complicated. Any help would be much appreciated.

Let me know if you need to know anything else.
Thanks,

**EDIT: Here is what the current script looks like if this helps:**

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

#Variables
$queryString;
$contentLength;
$number;
$sendmail="/usr/sbin/sendmail";

#Array Variable
@testarray;

#Hash Variable (Two-dimensional array that
#references its contents with keys and values
%testhash;

#################################################
##Read the envirionment variables              ##
#################################################
$contentLength = $ENV{"CONTENT_LENGTH"};
$return = "/thankyou";

############################################
##Make sure that there is data to read and##
##if there is, read it                    ##
############################################
if($contentLength != NULL){
    read(STDIN, $queryString, $contentLength);
}

###############################################################
##Split the information read in into an array in the         ##
##form of a list which contains the keys and values          ##
##as separate items. eg("key1","value1","key2","value2",etc.)##
###############################################################
@testarray = split(/&|=/,$queryString);

###############################################
##place the size of the array into a variable##
###############################################
$number = @testarray;

#############################################################
##Loop through each item in the array, convert the + to    ##
##spaces, convert the HEX into the character it represents,##
#############################################################
for ($counter = 0; $counter <= $number; $counter++){
    @testarray[$counter] =~ s/\+/ /g;
    @testarray[$counter] =~ s/%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/pack("c",hex($1))/ge;
}

#####################################################
##Place the contents of the array @testarray into  ##
##the hash variable %testhash. Each key in the hash##
##represents a value.                              ##
#####################################################
%testhash = @testarray;

######################
##Format the Message##
######################
$finalmailbody = "Conference Registration Form\n\n";


$finalmailbody .= "Morning Presenters:  $testhash{ece_classes},\n\n";


$finalmailbody .= "Payment Type:        $testhash{Payment_Type}\n\n";
$finalmailbody .= "Title:           $testhash{Title}\n";
$finalmailbody .= "First Name:      $testhash{First_Name}\n";
$finalmailbody .= "Last Name:       $testhash{Last_Name}\n";


##############################################
##Open the email message and send the email.##
##############################################
open(MAILREGISTRATION, "|$sendmail -oi -t") || die  "Can't open pipe to $sendmail: $!\n";
print MAILREGISTRATION "To: person\@website.ca\n";
print MAILREGISTRATION "From: $testhash{Email}\n"; 
print MAILREGISTRATION "Subject: Conference Submission\n\n";

#############################################
##Place the body of the email message here.##
#############################################
print MAILREGISTRATION "$finalmailbody";

close(MAILREGISTRATION) or die "Can't close pipe to $sendmail: $!\n";

#############################################
##Place the body of the email message here.##
#############################################
#print MAILCONFIRM "$finalmailbody";

#close(MAILCONFIRM) or die "Can't close pipe to $sendmail: $!\n";

########################
##Output to a web page##
########################
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML>\n";
print "<HEAD>\n";
print "  <META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=0;URL=$return>\n";
print "</HEAD>\n";
print "<BODY>\n";
print "</BODY>\n";
print "</HTML>\n";
```

Comment: You really need to provide more detail.

Comment: Also, please clarify what you're looking to find out. I've read your question a few times and still can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi @Oesor what I'm looking for in the end is to somehow supply the information that is in the checkbox fields "ece_classes" to the email address that the form submits to. I can't figure out how to "print" in the email the 3 selected classes that use the same "name" variable.

Comment: Also, if there's a better form that I could use, I'd be willing to look at that as well.

Answer (score 0):

That script is a (old old old OLD) script that reads in the posted data and splits it into key - value pairs that are stored in %testhash. The class name is the value of the exe_classes key.

Comment: so do you have any suggestions then?